Plotting related multiple plots sharing an axis but each disjoint from each other
I want to plot related multiple plots sharing an axis but each disjoint from each other, i.e., same x-axis feature and scale but each of the other features has their own separate y-axis region with it's own scale. I looked it up extensively in Seaborn and Plotly and tried taking help from LLMs as well, but the closest I could find was FacetFrid in seaborn. How is this done? Even if in some other software/tool if not python.
An exact representation of my desired plot is shown below:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355285265/figure/fig3/AS:11431281174467801@1689240361261/Late-Holocene-temperature-and-hydrological-changes-a-Late-Holocene-climate-anomalies.png

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355285265/figure/fig3/AS:11431281174467801@1689240361261/Late-Holocene-temperature-and-hydrological-changes-a-Late-Holocene-climate-anomalies.png
